# Filter dotnet test when the F# test name contains a space character

Tags: unit-testing, f#, dotnet-cli

Using the `dotnet test --filter` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details), how do I filter on F#-defined test names that include space characters in the name?

For example, with this unit test:

```ml
[<Fact>]
let ``When passing A to function B it returns C``() =
    Assert.True(true)
```

How do I run this specific test?

Answer (score 4):

You may workaround it by using the *"contains"*(`~`) operator (implied for FQDNs) and replacing all spaces (or other invalid characters) with a logical-and(`&`) operator like this:

```bash
dotnet test --filter "When&passing&A&to&function&B&it&returns&C"
```

For other [`--filter` predicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest), eg. `[Category="spacious   testcase"]` it would become:

```bash
--filter "category~spacious&category~testcase"
```

---

##### Reason:

The `dotnet test` command uses *test_adapters* for parsing filter expressionss, and as of Dec 2022 both adapters from *VisualStudio*(default) and *NUnit3* fail with spaces in the right-hand-side of a predicate, reported in [nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter#876](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/876).  By keeping just the "good parts" of the rhs-value and AND-ing them together, you achieve some accuracy in picking the desired test-cases.